# How to check the swap partion in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk

I found a strange thing, the result of `free` shows:

```sh
> free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        6060516     1258584     3614828       34340     1187104     4469908
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

But the result of `df`:

```sh
> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           592M  1.9M  591M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        98G   85G  8.8G  91% /
tmpfs           2.9G   40K  2.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
...
/dev/loop18     2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/730
tmpfs           592M   32K  592M   1% /run/user/1000
```

There is no swap partion ... I use default config to build ubuntu18.04 in VMWare

```
> uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is the swap partition enabled in the system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swap partition is not a file system and as a consequence is not displayed by df which works only on *file systems*.

Instead you can use swapon:

```
$ swapon
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swap.img file   2G   0B   -2
```

Comment: So, you mean the swap is a part of the file system ? I saw in ubuntu 16 there has a swap partion in dl, but in ubuntu 18 there is not

Comment: No: a swap partition is not a file system and this is why it is not displayed by df. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/846163/does-swap-space-have-a-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Other than swapon suggested by pifor you can also check your partition, swap included, with lsblk command:

`$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   80G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0   79G  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0   27G  0 lvm  /home`